# If a double integral does not converge absolutely, does that mean the function is discontinuous?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, continuity, fubini-tonelli-theorems

An assumption of Fubini's theorem is that:
$$\displaystyle{\iint_{R} |f(x,y)| \thinspace \mathrm{d} A < \infty}$$
If this assumption is not met, and the integral of the absolute value of the function is infinite, does that imply that the function is discontinuous at some point in the region R?

If the assumption is met, is that the same thing as saying that f(x,y) is continuous over R?

Edit: This question is based on Fubini's theorem for rectangular regions.

Comment: What type of region $R$ are you considering?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Just a rectangular region.

Comment: Have you tried looking for counterexamples?

Comment: The answer depends on whether the rectangle is closed or open (or neither).

Comment: @RobertIsrael I've messed around with Geogebra's 3D plotter for a bit and it does appear that when the absolute integral is infinite, the function isn't continuous over R. An example would be $$\frac{x^2-y^2){(x^2+y^2)^2$$. If you integrate that for x between 0 and 1, and y between 0 and 1, the function is discontinuous at (0,0). However, I don't know if saying that the integral of the absolute value is finite is synonymous with continuous over R?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy A closed rectangular region is what I'm considering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, provided that $R$ is closed (I assume this will be the case since this looks like a Calculus III question, and we tend to use closed regions for that course). You can use the fact that if $R$ is a closed and bounded region, then if $f(x,y)$ is continuous, $|f(x,y)|$ must obtain a maximum somewhere. Call it $M$. Then 
$$-M\cdot A(R) \leq \iint |f(x,y)|dA \leq M\cdot A(R)$$
where $A(R)$ is the area of the rectangular region.

If you want a function that does not work on an open region, consider
$$f(x,y) = \frac{1}{x}$$
on the region $R = (0,1)\times (0,1)$. Then $f(x,y)$ is continuous on $R$, yet the integral is infinite.

Comment: So then Fubini's theorem wouldn't work if f(x,y) were 1/x with that region, despite the function being continuous on that region?

Comment: Yes, and that's why we usually like to take our regions to be $closed$ rectangular regions. The region $R$ that makes the second example go bad is a rectangle without a border.

Comment: Ah okay I see. So the border where x = 0 isn't actually a border because the function doesn't actually exist along that line. So in summary, would I be right in saying that for a closed, bounded rectangular region, a function being continuous over that region would always imply that the integral of the absolute value of that function is finite?

Comment: Yes, that's right.  However, for your second question, it's very easy to find discontinuous functions where the integral of the absolute value is finite.

Comment: @RobertIsrael So is the requirement for Fubini's theorem that the function be continuous or the integral of the absolute value be finite?

Comment: Fubini's theorem says nothing about continuity, but uses Lebesgue measure (or more generally two $\sigma$-finite measures) and requires a measurable function such that the integral of the absolute value of the function is finite.  You may be using Riemann integration rather than Lebesgue, in which case it is convenient to assume continuity.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Okay thank you!